# Tile animation using Metro JS

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to combine two animations using the [metro js](http://www.drewgreenwell.com/projects/metrojs) plugin. I want to combine the [multiple stops](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/D9usk/presentation/) animation with the [flip animation](http://jsfiddle.net/drewgreenwell/UR6HB/presentation/). The flip animation should happen after a delay. Can you help me get started with some sample code?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how much of a hack you are looking for.

There is a short and dirty method for doing this, but I can't promise it will work cross browser, and you will also have to carefully tune if you care about sync issues.

To explain, you can embed one tile inside a frame of another tile, but the interior tile will not be "smart" as to whether it is being displayed or not: it will not reset its animation each time it is shown again.

If you start with a flip tile as the outside animation, then embed a multiple stops tile as the first side shown of the flip, you can have multiple stops show, then the tile flips.

What becomes tricky in this is that the `delay` value is just that: a delay *between* animations, but not accounting for the time the animation runs. In order to show all of the stops of the multiple stops tile before flipping, your flip tile's delay must be: `number-of-stops * ( multiple-stops-tile-delay + multiple-stops-tile-single-animation-time ) - flip-tile-single-animation-time`

**[Here is an example jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWLFZ/8/)** (I simply modified the two examples given) where the delay for the flip tile is not set long enough, because I couldn't be bothered to calculate/code dive the ms animation times. I simply used number-of-stops * delay-time instead. So with the multiple stops tile set to a 6000 delay with 3 stops, I set the parent flip tile to an 18000 delay. If you let this run for more than a couple flips it will be quite out of sync.

**Note:** I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox, and IE 9 and it basically works in all three, but IE may have weird delay timing different from the other two, which may make stops to flip syncing in all three browsers impossible.

The longer and more elegant method would involve code changes to the plugin to force animation reset for tiles inside of other tiles, or some similar approach, but going beyond simply pointing that out would be outside of the scope of a straightforward answer.